# Python: Extracting time stamps from a log between two lines

Tags: python, debugging

I am quite new to Python, I am trying to write a script which extracts TimeStamps of few Lines of a Log.

The logs looks something like this.

```
-----------------------------------------------
138976 2013-12-17 18:25:58.607 superman(759) Debug: {event} TUNE: IR Signal Received: Key Code: 104

138977 2013-12-17 18:25:58.616 mediamanager(763) Debug: {event} TUNE: Player Close Issued

138999 2013-12-17 18:25:58.683 mediamanager(763) Debug: {event} TUNE: Player Open Issued: atsc://fr783000000.256.10

139003 2013-12-17 18:25:58.688 mediamanager(763) Debug: {event} TUNE: Streamer Opened: atsc://fr783000000.256.10 SessionId=152 ProcessID=856

139014 2013-12-17 18:25:58.695 halserver(628) Debug: {event} TUNE: Frontend Locked: Tuner: 1

139030 2013-12-17 18:25:58.735 mediamanager(763) Debug: {event} TUNE: Player Play Issued: SessionId: 152


139133 2013-12-17 18:25:59.705 httpmediaserver(824) Debug: {event} TUNE: HTTP Request Received: HEAD /mediasession?producer_id=8&type=tune_live HTTP/1.1

139134 2013-12-17 18:25:59.757 halserver(628) Debug: {event} TUNE: New Picture Received

139136 2013-12-17 18:25:59.757 halserver(628) Debug: {event} TUNE: Video Is Visible
---------------------------------------
```

Basically there are few other unwanted lines as well in between.
Few of the lines here appear randomly as well, what i am looking for is to extract the data when the Tune Events appear in this sequence.

Can anybody give some idea on it.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Hi @dashX, I've tried to improve the formatting of your post but you might want to check whether those lines of hyphens should be included in the data or not.

Comment: Sounds like a job for grep, i.e. ```grep -P '^\d+ \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3} '```

Comment: So what is your desired result? A list with all the timestamps of the lines that contain 'TUNE'? A dictionary, that should also contain the line number? Please be more specific...

Comment: @HerrActress The idea is to get the Timestamps i.e between "TUNE: IR Signal Received: Key Code: 104" and "TUNE: Video Is Visible" . Basically in the log file these patterns appear quite frequent. I want to extract all the time between these two TUNE events.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I am still not sure what you are asking. You either want to collect only the time stamps between the two events in a list or something or do you want to find out the time between the two events based on a log file?

```
import re

with open('my_log.txt') as my_log:
  a = [re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}',
      line)[0] for line in my_log.readlines() if 'TUNE:' in line]
print a
```

Output if you want the time stamps in a list:

```
['2013-12-17 18:25:58.607', '2013-12-17 18:25:58.616',
 '2013-12-17 18:25:58.683', '2013-12-17 18:25:58.688',
 '2013-12-17 18:25:58.695', '2013-12-17 18:25:58.735',
 '2013-12-17 18:25:59.705', '2013-12-17 18:25:59.757',
 '2013-12-17 18:25:59.757']
```

Output if you want to know time delta between the first and last events:

```
from dateutil import parser

t_delta = parser.parse(a[-1]) - parser.parse(a[0])
print t_delta #0:00:01.150000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . One doubt here, could you please break this up and explain "[0] for line in my_log.readlines() if 'TUNE:' in line"    what is the significance of [0]?

Comment: You are welcome. `re.findall()` will return a list with all the results matching the pattern. `[0]` means take just the first element from that list. If this is the answer you were looking for you could accept it. It will increase our reputation, plus it will help others know this question was resolved.